# Making Graph Calls Client Side

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am building a Teams application that will use Microsoft Graph to add and remove rows from a SharePoint list. I have taken a look at a number of examples provided in the Teams-Toolkit extension in VSCode including [Graph Toolkit Contacts Exporter](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx-Samples/tree/v2/graph-toolkit-contact-exporter) and [Hello World Tab With Backend](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx-Samples/tree/v2/hello-world-tab-with-backend). The examples have left me confused about weather I can safely make Graph calls directly from the client side, since in both examples have done so?

- Is it safe to make graph calls from the client side when using the TeamsSDK?
- Does this expose a token in an unsafe browser?
- Should I instead be making graph calls server side? e.g. using the on behalf of flow or is that only relevant if you are interfacing with API's where you have a single application level api key?

Answer (score 1):

While it hasn't really been explicit, it certainly seems to me that the guidance has changed on this over time from Microsoft, and these days they're definitely steering people to making the calls server side instead, for exactly the reason you state - the token is quite privileged, and so should not be passed around to an unsafe browser.

To see more on this, here is a video from Microsoft: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kruUnaZgQaY, and the same content is available in written (blog) format here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/lets-decode-single-sign-on-sso-in-microsoft-teams-tabs/ . Essentially, it refers to [this blog post](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/securely-connect-microsoft-graph-teams-tabs-sso/) which essentially just says to do it all server side (get and immediately use the OBO). It means that you kind of need "double" code (you need to have code to make the call client side, which calls your own API, which then has calls to Graph), but it's safer and you're of course only doing this for specific things you need in Graph, not the -entire- Graph surface area.

Comment: @Anthony Phan- Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved with above suggestion or still looking for any help?

Comment: Thanks @Hilton :) Although I can see the new guidance from the video it does not explain well why this would be a larger surface area? The token you receive would only have access to scopes defined in your app registration not the entire graph. Additionally the token you get from teams can easily be used to call the your back end to receive the same data and this token is available client side ? it feel like its just applying security by obscurity by making a party call your back end instead of the Microsoft Graph

Comment: The SSO token you get back can't actually call the Graph - it can only call your own backend - that's all it's got scope to do. If you try call Graph with it, it will fail I think. The only way to call the Graph, therefore, is to exchange for an "OBO" token, so you need to do that -anyway-. The question becomes whether you now pass this OBO back to the client, and let it call Graph using that, or whether you keep the OBO only within your backend. As this token is quite privileged (it can do anything your user can, based on the scopes requested), it's safer to never expose it over the wire.

Comment: So, to your point, it's not 'security by obscurity' because you're not 'obscuring' the token - you're never sending it anywhere outside your backend, so there's no chance of it ever leaking out. It's definitely a more secure design, but it means your API surface area is wider, essentially with 'gateway' operations tunnelling to matching Graph operations. Obviously, it's not the entire Graph surface area, it's just what your user needs to do as part of what your app is for.

Comment: @AnthonyPhan-Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved with above suggestion or still looking for any help?

Comment: are you able to comment on how the OBO flow compares to Authorization Code Flow with Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE)? they both seem to be recommended by Microsoft but one requires a back end (OBO)

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but in this case I think that, basically, the PKCE is the front-end flow, doing the authentication of the user, whereas the OBO should happen server side, and essentially it's doing the authorisation for the specific operation to be performed. This is a bit of an oversimplication, but it's possibly a useful model to think about it with.